VS Code terminal showing "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code" directory in terminal header instead of current directory
After recent update of VS Code to 1.89.1, it shows "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code" in terminal header instead of the current directory where I open it from.
See image below (I've made sensitive information hidden):

I am curious what have changed since VS Code 1.88

I'm having the same problem, and it only happens with Git Bash not Cmd or PowerShell

Inspired by this thread, I found this fix working for me:
Firstly, go to Settings and type terminal.integrated.profiles.windows (I am on Windows) and select Edit in settings.json.
Then edit the values under "Git Bash" such that:
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash",
            "args": ["--cd=."],
        }
    },

You could also do "args": ["--cd=${workspaceFolder}"], as suggested by one of the answers in the link above. I chose . to avoid issues with multiproject workspace.

double thumbs up, life saving!
